# Разница типов

Tags: c#, строки

Вот в процессе разработки "недетского" приложения на C# возник совсем "детский" вопрос:
"Есть ли разница между двумя данными типами?":

```
String str1;
string str2;
```

Comment: Мне вот тоже интересно, как начинающему программисту на C#. Могу лишь предположить, что разницы нет никакой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, `string` - это аллиас класса `String`, так же как `int` - аллиас `Int32`, `long` - `Int64` и прочее.

Вот таблица из книги Рихтера "CLR via С#"

[image: types]

Что он говорит по этому поводу:

> Я не могу согласиться со следующим утверждением из спецификации языка 
> С#: «С точки зрения стиля программирования предпочтительней использовать
> ключевое слово, а не полное системное имя типа». Я стараюсь использовать имена 
> типов FCL и избегать имен элементарных типов. На самом деле мне бы хотелось, 
> чтобы имен элементарных типов не было совсем, а разработчики употребляли 
> только имена FCL-типов.

И приводит аргументы почему, почитайте, хорошая книга.

Comment: Спасибо. Я, скажем так, об этом догадывался, но, например, если рассмотреть целочисленные типы, как алиасы, то в этом есть смысл. Так, long, в отличии от int/int32 может вместить большее значение. С int32 По отношению к int64 тоже все более-менее понятно. 

---
А вот как же понимать одноименный "алиасный" тип string по отношению к String ?

Answer (score 2):

Просто `string` - это алиас класса `String()`, т.е. в коде пишем string тоже что `new System.String`

короче говоря

```
string x = new System.String(' ', 5);
```

Вот список пвсевдонимов CLR Типов:

Пвсевдоним          CLR тип

```
string  System.String
sbyte   System.SByte
byte    System.Byte
short   System.Int16
ushort  System.UInt16
int     System.Int32
uint    System.UInt32
long    System.Int64
ulong   System.UInt64
char    System.Char
float   System.Single
double  System.Double
bool    System.Boolean
```

Comment: Т.е можно посчитать так:

    using System.String = string;

???

Comment: это класс, но не пространство имен

Comment: Это, как сокращение:

    using string = System.String;

функционалом чем-то похожее не #typedef в C++