# Есть ли разница между int и System.Int32?

Tags: c#, .net

Слышал байку, что если писать так `int i = 0`, а не `System.Int32 i = 0` или

```
using System;
.......
Int32 i = 0;
```

происхожит какая-то оптимизация*. 
Есть ли какая-то разница между этими вариантами?

*Количество набранных символов и т.д. не учитывать.

Comment: int - это и есть синоним для System.Int32, никаких других "оптимизаций" в литературе я не встречал.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Псевдонимы(алиасы) в перечисления - правила использования (c#)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/496085/186999)

Comment: И еще один: [Разница типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/123545/186999)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Разницы никакой, `int` и `Int32` после компиляции в *IL* код станут одним и тем же. `int` это ключевое слово для c#, ровно как `Integer` для *VisualBasic*, но оба они представляют собой `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 6):

**`int`** - примитив, доступный в компиляторе C#, в то время как **`Int32`** является типом [FCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Class_Library) и следовательно доступен для всех языков, соответствующих CLS.

Answer (score 5):

В C# `int` - это simple type, алиаз `System.Int32`.

Есть только один случай, когда упоминание типа допустимо, а упоминание алиаза - нет. Это конструкция `nameof`:

```
// компилируется
string name = nameof(Int32);

// ошибка
string name = nameof(int);
```

Во всех остальных случаях нет никакой разницы между `int`, `System.Int32` и `using System` + `Int32`. - все превратится в одно и то же упоминание типа `System.Int32` в результирующей сборке.

Comment: @Grundy закрыл.

Comment: *Во всех остальных случаях нет никакой разницы* А как насчёт `(int)-1` и `(System.Int32)-1`?

Comment: @PetSerAl хм, не знал, спасибо за пример. Допишу в ответ, как доберусь до стационарного компа.